# No semaphore arrays

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel

I am using Ubuntu 20.

```
uname -a
Linux peyman-Ubuntu 5.4.0-48-generic #52-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 10 10:58:49 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

when I use ipcs command , no semaphore arrays displayed.
Is is possible that linux does nlot use semaphore arrays or problem is something else?

```
sudo ipcs -s

------ Semaphore Arrays --------
key        semid      owner      perms      nsems
```

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so, please accept it with the tick mark

Answer (score 0):

There are no semaphore arrays because you haven't created any. A pair of shell commands to manage semaphore arrays and other System V inter-process communication (IPC) features is `ipcmk` and `ipcrm`.

For example

```
ipcmk --semaphore 3       # Create an array of three semaphores with id 0
```

And

```
ipcrm --semaphore-id 0    # Remove semaphore array with id 0
```